# Flutter http.get doesn't return all the requested data

Tags: flutter, http

I am building a small news app.
When I fetch the data - I receive only a few of the initial articles, the rest are null. But when I open the link in the browser - I get a 100 articles as it should be.
Please help, what am I doing wrong?

I call an http.get method inside initState which returns a jsonDecode, which I then use for a ListView.builder - FutureBuilder - ListView.builder combination.

As a result I get only 2-5 articles and the rest are giving me `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'` errors.

The code:

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(kLink);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  late Future data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    data = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('News'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return TileFutureBuilder(data: data);
        },
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}

class TileFutureBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const TileFutureBuilder({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Future data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: data,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
      ) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data['articles'].length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return NewsTile(mapData: snapshot.data['articles'][index]);
            },
          );

          // NewsTile(mapData: snapshot.data['articles'][0]);
        } else {
          return const NewsTilePlaceholder();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my option,

1. You should build **model** for API response rather than catch `response.body`.
2. As a result of building **model**, you can easily trace your **null** problem.

Your problem is, in your `snapshot.data['articles']`, some or all data (Eg: maybe **Map** or **List**)contain **null** values. For now you can easily solve by adding this `snapshot.data['articles']??''`.

Comment: Thank you! After I've built a model I found the issues, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

**Check if the return value is null**

```
 snapshot.data['articles'][index]??""
```